# How to run Selenium webdriver script in mulitple browser without changing parameters - java

Tags: selenium, junit

I want to run my webdriver script in multiple browser one after other after running it only once. In my current framework, i have kept all browser names in properties file and from there i am fetching it and passing as parameter. But the problem is in this way, in one execution it runs for only one browser. If i want to run it in another browser, i have to pass 2nd browser name for the second execution. 
I want to run it once and the script should execute for one browser then after that automatically should run for other browser also.i  am using Junit.
How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to Seleniun [Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) or you could create a TestSuite and use System properties to set the browser.

something like this:

1- Create the testSuite with all you testcases

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ MyClassTest.class, MySecondClassTest.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

2- Run the suites setting the properties first

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

    public class MyTestRunner {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Set browser
        System.setProperty("browser","Firefox");
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(AllTests.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
          System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }

        System.setProperty("browser","Explorer");
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(AllTests.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
          System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
        //.... Rest of the browsers .... //
      }
    }
```

3- With this option you should get the property and setUp your test (`System.getProperty("browser");`)

```
public class MyClassTest{
    private webDriver = new webDriver();

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        String browser = System.getProperty("browser");
        if(browser.equals("Firefox"))
            this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        else if(browser.equals("Explorer")
            this.driver = new .....

        .....
    }

    //Your tests
    @Test
    -....
```

Hope helps!

Comment: Thanks @Morvader i got your point to run the class by creating a test suite. Could you pls explain what you are doing in MyTestRunner.. is it only for setting the property value in properties file. where to use the getproperty method to fetch browser names

Answer (score 0):

After implementing in the way @Morvader mentioned, i got the thing done and worked fine.

I found one more way to do the same thing without creating an extra class i.e. the Testrunner class.

By using @RunWith(Parameterized.class), this can be achieved in much simpler way. Overhead of creating extra TestRunner class is not needed in this approach. Thought of sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` for test suites (`@RunWith(Suite.class)`), you will see that in standard JUnit 4 there's no combination of both.

You can either implement your own `Runner` or use an extension library like [this one](https://github.com/PeterWippermann/parameterized-suite).